# In cpp implementation of graph, nodes should be stored in template vector or list?

Tags: list, vector, graph

Which is more efficient while keeping in mind, the cache misses in case of lists vs iterator invalidation in vector?

Comment: What type of graph? For what problem? What operations? This is impossible to answer without more detail. Iterator invalidation occurs only in certain cases, which also depend on the particular operation performed on the graph.

Comment: I am a beginner at graphs. I was implementing my very first algorithm for finding shortest path in simple graph with numbers as nodes.